# Image flickers on first load in ReactNative

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am trying to build a ReactNative Application with an animated button. The problem is that this animation does not work correctly the first time after the App is started. There is some white flickering. But after the animation ran wrong the first time everything works as expected:

[image: Animation of the problem.]

I have already tried to preload the image in several ways, but without any success.

This is my minimal working example, note that if there are several different images the flickering occurs if a new image is loaded (e.g. I have two blue buttons and after I tapped the first one, the second one will work fine, but if I then tap an orange button it once again flickers for the first time, at least if I have not tapped another orange button after app start.):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback, View, Image, ScrollView, 
Button, BackHandler} from 'react-native';

export default class Touchables extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {alarm1: (<Image source={require("./assets/alarmoff.png")} 
  style={styles.imageButton}/>),

    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
  //trying to preload all Images, but it does not help.
    (<Image source={require("./assets/alarmon.png")} style= 
      {styles.imageButton}/>)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.contentContainer}>

     <View style={{flex: 3, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPressIn={() => this.setState({alarm1: 
             <Image source={require("./assets/alarmon.png")} style={styles.imageButton}/>})} onPressOut={() => this.setState({alarm1:  <Image source={require("./assets/alarmoff.png")} style={styles.imageButton}/>})}>
            <View style={styles.button}>
              {this.state.alarm1}
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          <Text style={styles.text}>This button flickers on first click. Restart App completly to see the issue. Reloading is not enough.</Text>
        </View>
       </View>
       <View>
        <Button
         onPress={() => BackHandler.exitApp()}
         title="Exit App"
         color="#841584"
         accessibilityLabel="Android only I guess."
        />
       </View>

     </ScrollView>
   );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 2,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginBottom: 30
 },
 button: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 10,
    marginBottom: 20,
    shadowColor: '#303838',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 5 },
    shadowRadius: 10,
    shadowOpacity: 0
  },
  contentContainer: {
    paddingVertical: 20,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
 text:{
    color: '#000',
    marginBottom: 30
 },
 imageButton: {
   flex: 1,
   width: 240,
   height: 200,
   marginBottom: -15,
   marginTop: 10,
   resizeMode: 'cover'
 }
});
```

So my question is how can I stop the image from flickering after app start?

The full version of the little demo app I have build to show my problem is available on my [Github Repository](https://github.com/FrankenApps/AlarmButton)

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6971

Answer (score 3):

There may be a performance issue while loading different resolution images. You can use https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image module to load images.

you can add and link it as below

```
# Install
yarn add react-native-fast-image

# Automatic linking. (other linking methods listed below)
react-native link react-native-fast-image
```

after that u can import it and use it using like below example

```
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image'

    const YourImage = () =>
      <FastImage
        style={styles.image}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://unsplash.it/400/400?image=1',
          headers:{ Authorization: 'someAuthToken' },
          priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
        }}
        resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
      />
```

I copied this example from that repo. you can find documentation also there. Try it. It will increase image loading performance. Then most probably flickering issue will be resolved.

Comment: Thank you for that hint. The problem is that it seems like I can not use local images with this module, which is quite important in my case.

Comment: @frankenapps as far as I know, the local image also need relevant resolution for relevant devices. otherwise, the image will be converted for relevant type and show. maybe it causes your problem.

Comment: react-native-fast-image repository looks dead, be careful choosing this path https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/issues/685

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was causing flickering issues when I put the Image component in a FlatList ListHeaderComponent component. So,

- Code causing flickering:

  `ListHeaderComponent={HeadComponent}`

The HeadComponent was basically inside `render` and had the code `const HeadComponent = () => { return (<Image...`

- Code that fixed flickering:

  `ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}`

The `renderHeader` is a function that returned the same thing as `HeadComponent` using code `renderHeader () { return (<Image...`

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

It was causing flickering issues when I put the Image component in a FlatList ListHeaderComponent component

In order to solve the issue I added useCallBack hook

```
const ListComponent = useCallBack(() => {
// your code
}, [])

ListHeaderComponent={ListComponent}
```

For me it solved the flickering issue

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who still have this problem : this is another way to fix

```
<Image
     source={{ uri: your_path }}
     defaultSource={{ uri: your_path }}
     resizeMode="cover"
     style={{width: 100,height: 100}} />
```

Answer (score 1):

A stupid way：

```js
<ImageBackground
  defaultSource={require('./ui/pay0.png')}
  source={require('./ui/pay0.png')}
  style={{flex: 1, position: 'relative', zIndex: 9999, elevation: 5}}
/>
{/* Cache the remaining pictures to prevent flickering */}
<ImageBackground
  source={require('./ui/pay1.png')}
  style={{position: 'absolute', width: 1, height: 1}}
/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Well I have a workaround (sort of..).
In my `componentDidMount()` I do now set the button to its pressed state, wait for some time until the image is displayed and scaled, and then I set the state to off again, like so:

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.setState({alarm1: <Image source={require("./assets/alarmon.png")} style={styles.imageButton}/>})
   setTimeout(()=>{this.setState({alarm1: <Image source={require("./assets/alarmoff.png")} style={styles.imageButton}/>})}, 1000); 
}
```

I tried to lower the timeout to less than a second, but then on my old (and slow) phone the flickering started again on first press after app load.

This obviously leads to the button state beeing changed after the app loaded, but if all buttons flicker once after app start, that is better than every button flickering on first press in my opinion.

I would however be glad if anybody could tell me the real way, how to resolve this.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using expo, you can use `Asset.loadAsync`. See: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/asset.

In `App.js`, I like to wait for all static assets to be loaded before showing any screen.