# Add animatable Items to Flatlist horizontal items

Tags: react-native, react-native-animatable

I have flat list horizontal like below , I am trying to add bounce effect when I swipe right and when new item gets visible to the view.

```
const Item = ({ title, image, index }) => (
  <Animatable.View>
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  </Animatable.View>
);

const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
  <Item title={item.title} image={item.image} index={index} />
);

const [viewableItemsIndices, setViewableItemsIndices] = useState([]);

const handleVieweableItemsChanged = useCallback(
  ({ viewableItems, changed }) => {
    setViewableItemsIndices(viewableItems.map((item) => item.index));
  },
  []
);

const viewabilityConfig = useRef({
  itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 80,
}).current;
return (
  <SafeAreaView style={style.container}>
    <View style={style.flatlistContainer}>
      <FlatList
        snapToInterval={120}
        horizontal={true}
        data={DATA.map((item, i) => {
          item.isViewable = viewableItemsIndices.find((ix) => ix == i);
          return item;
        })}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        onViewableItemsChanged={handleVieweableItemsChanged}
        viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
        extraData={viewableItemsIndices}
      />
    </View>
    <Text>Items that should be visible:</Text>
    {viewableItemsIndices.map((i) => (
      <Text> {DATA[i].title}</Text>
    ))}
  </SafeAreaView>
);
```

I have all the visible items in flatlist in **viewableItemsIndices** , now how do I following animatable animation to individual item based on its index..

```
 const AnimationRef = useRef(null);
  const _onPress = () => {
    if(AnimationRef) {
      AnimationRef.current?.bounce();
    }
  }
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={_onPress}>
      <Animatable.View ref={AnimationRef}>
        <Text>Bounce me!</Text>
      </Animatable.View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
```

Edit : Below is complete code

```
import React , { useState, useRef,useCallback } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, Image , View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons, MaterialCommunityIcons , FontAwesome5 } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import FlatListWrapper from "../anim/flatwrapper";

const FlatListAnimation = () => {
  const DATA = [
    {
      id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
      title: 'First  Item Item Item',
      image : 'https://res.cloudinary.com/Sony-liv/image/fetch/c_fill,e_brightness:10,f_auto,fl_lossy,h_494,q_auto:low,w_344/https://origin-staticv2.sonyliv.com/portrait_thumb/scam_Lang_Protrait_Thumb.jpg'
    },
    {
      id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
      title: 'Second Item',
      image : 'https://res.cloudinary.com/Sony-liv/image/fetch/c_fill,e_brightness:10,f_auto,fl_lossy,h_494,q_auto:low,w_344/https://origin-staticv2.sonyliv.com/portrait_thumb/Ramsingh-CharlieA_07062021_Lang_Protrait_Thumb.jpg'
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
      title: 'Third Item',
      image : 'https://res.cloudinary.com/Sony-liv/image/fetch/c_fill,e_brightness:10,f_auto,fl_lossy,h_494,q_auto:low,w_344/https://origin-staticv2.sonyliv.com/portrait_thumb/6028647473001.jpg'
  
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0sdsf-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
      title: 'Third Item',
      image : 'https://res.cloudinary.com/Sony-liv/image/fetch/c_fill,e_brightness:10,f_auto,fl_lossy,h_494,q_auto:low,w_344/https://origin-staticv2.sonyliv.com/portrait_thumb/6033313370001.jpg'
  
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0f-3ddsda1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
      title: 'Third Item',
      image : 'https://res.cloudinary.com/Sony-liv/image/fetch/c_fill,e_brightness:10,f_auto,fl_lossy,h_494,q_auto:low,w_344/https://origin-staticv2.sonyliv.com/portrait_thumb/6033325319001_v2.jpg'
  
    },
    {
      id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad531abb28ba',
      title: 'First  Item Item Item',
      image : 'https://res.cloudinary.com/Sony-liv/image/fetch/c_fill,e_brightness:10,f_auto,fl_lossy,h_494,q_auto:low,w_344/https://origin-staticv2.sonyliv.com/portrait_thumb/scam_Lang_Protrait_Thumb.jpg'
    },
    {
      id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd912aa97f63',
      title: 'Second Item',
      image : 'https://res.cloudinary.com/Sony-liv/image/fetch/c_fill,e_brightness:10,f_auto,fl_lossy,h_494,q_auto:low,w_344/https://origin-staticv2.sonyliv.com/portrait_thumb/Ramsingh-CharlieA_07062021_Lang_Protrait_Thumb.jpg'
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-1455371e29d72',
      title: 'Third Item',
      image : 'https://res.cloudinary.com/Sony-liv/image/fetch/c_fill,e_brightness:10,f_auto,fl_lossy,h_494,q_auto:low,w_344/https://origin-staticv2.sonyliv.com/portrait_thumb/6028647473001.jpg'
  
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0sdsf-3da1-471f-bd96-1445571e29d72',
      title: 'Third Item',
      image : 'https://res.cloudinary.com/Sony-liv/image/fetch/c_fill,e_brightness:10,f_auto,fl_lossy,h_494,q_auto:low,w_344/https://origin-staticv2.sonyliv.com/portrait_thumb/6033313370001.jpg'
  
    },
  ];

      const maxlimit = 20;

// Item.js
const Item = (props) => { 
  const {
    item:{image , title, isViewable},
    index
  } = props
  let animation = null
  // set your animation type base on isViewable
  if(isViewable || isViewable == 0){
    animation = ""
  }
  else{
    animation = ""
  }
  
  return (
    //add animation to Animated.View


<Animatable.View style={style.itemContainer} >


    <Image
      resizeMode="contain"
      style={styles.tinyLogo}
      source={{
        uri: image,
      }}
    />
    
    </Animatable.View>



  );
}

      
      const renderItem = ({ item , index }) => (
        <Item title={item.title} image = {item.image} index= {index} />
      );

    // store the indices of the viewableItmes
    const [ viewableItemsIndices, setViewableItemsIndices ] = useState([]);

    const handleVieweableItemsChanged = useCallback(({viewableItems, changed }) => {   
        setViewableItemsIndices(viewableItems.map(item=>item.index))
    }, []);

    // config that decides when an item is viewable
    const viewabilityConfig = useRef({
      // useRef to try to counter the view rerender thing
      itemVisiblePercentThreshold:80
    }).current;
    // wrapped handleViewChange in useCallback to try to handle the re-render error
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={style.container}>
        <FlatListWrapper
          horizontal={true}
          //{/*give each data item an isViewable prop*/}
          data={DATA.map((item,i)=>{
            item.isViewable=viewableItemsIndices.find(ix=>ix == i)
            return item
          })}
          renderItem={item=><Item {...item}/>}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          onViewableItemsChanged={({viewableItems, changed})=>{
            // set viewableItemIndices to the indices when view change
            setViewableItemsIndices(viewableItems.map(item=>item.index))
          }}
          //{/*config that decides when an item is viewable*/} 
          viewabilityConfig={{itemVisiblePercentThreshold:80}}
          extraData={viewableItemsIndices}
        />
       {/* Extra stuff that just tells you what items should be visible*/}
        <Text>Items that should be visible:</Text>
        {viewableItemsIndices.map(i=><Text key={'text-'+i}>  {DATA[i].title}</Text>)}
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
  const style = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
      padding:10,
      alignItems:'center'
    },
    
    item:{
      borderWidth:1,
      padding:5,
      borderColor:'green',
    },
    itemContainer:{
      flex:1,
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      marginVertical: 8,
      width:120,
      alignItems:'center',
      marginHorizontal: 3,


    }
  })

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
    },
    item: {
      flex:1,
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      marginVertical: 8,
      width:120,
      alignItems:'center',
      marginHorizontal: 3,
    },
    title: {
      fontSize: 32,
    },
    tinyLogo: {
      borderRadius : 4,
      width: 150,
      height:150
    },
  });

  export default FlatListAnimation;
```

FlatWrapper.js

```
//FlatListWrapper
import React, {useRef, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { 
    View, StyleSheet, FlatList , 
} from 'react-native';

const FlatListWrapper = (props) => {

  // useRef to avoid onViewableItemsChange on fly error
  const viewabilityConfig = useRef({
    // useRef to try to counter the view rerender thing
    itemVisiblePercentThreshold:80
  }).current;
  // wrapped handleViewChange in useCallback to try to handle the onViewableItemsChange on fly error
  const onViewChange = useCallback(props.onViewableItemsChanged,[])
  return (
      <View style={style.flatlistContainer}>
        <FlatList
          {...props}
          horizontal={true}
          onViewableItemsChanged={onViewChange}
        />
      </View>
  );
}
const style = StyleSheet.create({
 
  flatlistContainer:{
    borderWidth:1,
    borderColor:'red',
    width:'100%',
  },
 
})
export default FlatListWrapper
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I think the flickering was caused by the `extraData` prop causing reloads of the Flatlist. After re-reading the Animatable docs, I found that there was a way to access Animatable View refs and call animations from that ref. Knowing that, it was no longer necessary to force the flatlist to re-render whenever the items on screen change, and that removed all the flickering I found

```js
import React , { useState, useRef,useCallback } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, Image , View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons, MaterialCommunityIcons , FontAwesome5 } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import FlatListWrapper from "../components/FlatListWrapper";



const FlatListAnimation = () => {
  const DATA = [
    {
      id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
      title: 'First  Item Item Item',
      image : 'https://res.cloudinary.com/Sony-liv/image/fetch/c_fill,e_brightness:10,f_auto,fl_lossy,h_494,q_auto:low,w_344/https://origin-staticv2.sonyliv.com/portrait_thumb/scam_Lang_Protrait_Thumb.jpg'
    },
    {
      id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
      title: 'Second Item',
      image : 'https://res.cloudinary.com/Sony-liv/image/fetch/c_fill,e_brightness:10,f_auto,fl_lossy,h_494,q_auto:low,w_344/https://origin-staticv2.sonyliv.com/portrait_thumb/Ramsingh-CharlieA_07062021_Lang_Protrait_Thumb.jpg'
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72-3-3',
      title: 'Third Item',
      image : 'https://res.cloudinary.com/Sony-liv/image/fetch/c_fill,e_brightness:10,f_auto,fl_lossy,h_494,q_auto:low,w_344/https://origin-staticv2.sonyliv.com/portrait_thumb/6028647473001.jpg'
  
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0sdsf-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72-4-4',
      title: 'Fourth Item',
      image : 'https://res.cloudinary.com/Sony-liv/image/fetch/c_fill,e_brightness:10,f_auto,fl_lossy,h_494,q_auto:low,w_344/https://origin-staticv2.sonyliv.com/portrait_thumb/6033313370001.jpg'
  
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0f-3ddsda1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72-5-5',
      title: 'Fifth Item',
      image : 'https://res.cloudinary.com/Sony-liv/image/fetch/c_fill,e_brightness:10,f_auto,fl_lossy,h_494,q_auto:low,w_344/https://origin-staticv2.sonyliv.com/portrait_thumb/6033325319001_v2.jpg'
  
    },
    {
      id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad531abb28ba-6-6',
      title: 'Sixth  Item Item Item',
      image : 'https://res.cloudinary.com/Sony-liv/image/fetch/c_fill,e_brightness:10,f_auto,fl_lossy,h_494,q_auto:low,w_344/https://origin-staticv2.sonyliv.com/portrait_thumb/scam_Lang_Protrait_Thumb.jpg'
    },
    {
      id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd912aa97f63-7-7',
      title: 'Seventh Item',
      image : 'https://res.cloudinary.com/Sony-liv/image/fetch/c_fill,e_brightness:10,f_auto,fl_lossy,h_494,q_auto:low,w_344/https://origin-staticv2.sonyliv.com/portrait_thumb/Ramsingh-CharlieA_07062021_Lang_Protrait_Thumb.jpg'
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-1455371e29d72-8-8',
      title: 'Eighth Item',
      image : 'https://res.cloudinary.com/Sony-liv/image/fetch/c_fill,e_brightness:10,f_auto,fl_lossy,h_494,q_auto:low,w_344/https://origin-staticv2.sonyliv.com/portrait_thumb/6028647473001.jpg'
  
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0sdsf-3da1-471f-bd96-1445571e29d72-9-9',
      title: 'Ninth Item',
      image : 'https://res.cloudinary.com/Sony-liv/image/fetch/c_fill,e_brightness:10,f_auto,fl_lossy,h_494,q_auto:low,w_344/https://origin-staticv2.sonyliv.com/portrait_thumb/6033313370001.jpg'
  
    },
  ];
  const maxlimit = 20;
    // store the indices of the viewableItmes
  const [ viewableItemsIndices, setViewableItemsIndices ] = useState([]);
  const itemRefs = useRef(
    DATA.map( item=> {})
  );
  
  const isScrollingForward = useRef(true);
  // use last and current scroll position to determine scroll direction
  const lastScrollPosition = useRef(0);
  const handleScroll = ({nativeEvent})=>{
    let currentPosition = nativeEvent.contentOffset.x
    isScrollingForward.current = currentPosition > lastScrollPosition.current
    lastScrollPosition.current = currentPosition
  }
    // Item.js
  const Item = (props) => { 
    let {
      item:{ image , title, isViewable },
      index
    } = props
    const itemContainer = isViewable ? styles.itemContainer : [styles.itemContainer]
    return (
      //add animation to Animated.View
      <Animatable.View style={itemContainer} ref={ref=>itemRefs[index]=ref} >
        <Image
          resizeMode="contain"
          style={styles.tinyLogo}
          source={{
            uri: image,
          }}
        />
      </Animatable.View>
    );
  }
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatListWrapper
        horizontal={true}
        //{/*give each data item an isViewable prop*/}
        data={DATA.map((item,i)=>{
          item.isViewable = viewableItemsIndices.findIndex(ix=>ix == i) >=0;
          return item
        })}
        renderItem={(item,i)=><Item {...item} />}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        onViewableItemsChanged={({viewableItems, changed})=>{
          // setViewableItemsIndices(viewableItems.map(item=>item.index))
          viewableItems.forEach(item=>{
            let itemRef = itemRefs[item.index];
            itemRef?.transitionTo({opacity:1})
          })
          changed.forEach(item=>{
            let itemRef = itemRefs[item.index];
            if(!item.isViewable)
              itemRef?.transitionTo({opacity:0})
          })
        }}
        //{/*config that decides when an item is viewable*/} 
        viewabilityConfig={{itemVisiblePercentThreshold:100}}
        onScroll={handleScroll}
        disableScrollMomentum={true}
      />
     {/* Extra stuff that just tells you what items should be visible*/}
      <Text>Items that should be visible:</Text>
      {viewableItemsIndices.map(i=><Text key={'text-'+i}>  {DATA[i].title}</Text>)}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
  
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    // flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
  },
  itemContainer: {
    opacity:0
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
  tinyLogo: {
    borderRadius : 4,
    width: 150,
    height:150
  },
});

  export default FlatListAnimation;
```

Comment: can you tell what is the change you did to remove flickering ? also please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68040602/flatlist-measure-items-x-position

Comment: I've been playing around with the code and to be honest, I am not sure what I did. I deleted unnecessary stuff, like the extra stylesheet. I've been playing around with it though, trying to use reanimatable and I found the flickering issue again

Answer (score 1):

That is one awesome library! Not having to bother with Animated.Value is really, really nice.

```js
// Item.js
const Item = (props) => { 
  const {
    item:{title, isViewable},
    index
  } = props
  let animation = null
  // set your animation type base on isViewable
  if(isViewable || isViewable == 0){
    animation = "bounceInLeft"
  }
  else{
    animation = "bounceOutLeft"
  }
  
  return (
    //add animation to Animated.View
    <Animatable.View style={style.itemContainer} animation = {animation}>
      <View style={style.item}>
        <Text style={style.title}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    </Animatable.View>
  );
}
```

```js
// main component
const FlatListAnimation = () => {

  // store the indices of the viewableItmes
  const [ viewableItemsIndices, setViewableItemsIndices ] = useState([]);
  
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={style.container}>
      <FlatListWrapper
        horizontal={true}
        //{/*give each data item an isViewable prop*/}
        data={DATA.map((item,i)=>{
          item.isViewable=viewableItemsIndices.find(ix=>ix == i)
          return item
        })}
        renderItem={item=><Item {...item}/>}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        onViewableItemsChanged={({viewableItems, changed})=>{
          // set viewableItemIndices to the indices when view change
          setViewableItemsIndices(viewableItems.map(item=>item.index))
        }}
        //{/*config that decides when an item is viewable*/} 
        viewabilityConfig={{itemVisiblePercentThreshold:80}}
        extraData={viewableItemsIndices}
      />
     {/* Extra stuff that just tells you what items should be visible*/}
      <Text>Items that should be visible:</Text>
      {viewableItemsIndices.map(i=><Text key={'text-'+i}>  {DATA[i].title}</Text>)}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    padding:10,
    alignItems:'center'
  },
  flatlistContainer:{
    borderWidth:1,
    borderColor:'red',
    width:'50%',
    height:40
  },
  item:{
    borderWidth:1,
    padding:5,
  },
  itemContainer:{
    padding:5,
  }
})
```

```js
//FlatListWrapper
import React, {useRef, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { 
    View, StyleSheet, FlatList , 
} from 'react-native';

const FlatListWrapper = (props) => {

  // useRef to avoid onViewableItemsChange on fly error
  const viewabilityConfig = useRef({
    // useRef to try to counter the view rerender thing
    itemVisiblePercentThreshold:80
  }).current;
  // wrapped handleViewChange in useCallback to try to handle the onViewableItemsChange on fly error
  const onViewChange = useCallback(props.onViewableItemsChanged,[])
  return (
      <View style={style.flatlistContainer}>
        <FlatList
          {...props}
          horizontal={true}
          onViewableItemsChanged={onViewChange}
        />
      </View>
  );
}
const style = StyleSheet.create({
 
  flatlistContainer:{
    borderWidth:1,
    borderColor:'red',
    width:'50%',
    height:40
  },
 
})
export default FlatListWrapper
```

Comment: Is this with flat list ? It looks like seperate component.. I want to do this with the all the viewableItemsIndices flatlist items like u answered in previous question...

Comment: Yes its with the FlatList. I only posted `Item` cuz it was the only component that I changed

Comment: for clarity, I added all of the other files

Comment: hi , thank you ,, Animation is working , but scroll is flickering white when I scroll the flatlist... Its flickering even when I remove the animation

Comment: And its only with image , If I remove the image there is no flickering.

Comment: How are you loading the image?

Comment: please check the question , I edited my code - <Image resizeMode="contain" style={styles.tinyLogo} source={{ uri: image, }} /> like this.

Comment: I haven't got any flickering. But according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53130480/image-flickers-on-first-load-in-reactnative keys can cause flickering. In your update I noticed that some of your ids, which are used as keys, are duplicates. Try making them all unique

Comment: Hi , Thanks I am doing my custom animation now... by measuring all the items  and getting its X position in the flat list  , thanks anyways.

Comment: i just got it to flicker sorry

Comment: I've added an answer that removed the flickering

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is edit the animation in `Item`. I have replaced fadeIn and fadeOut with slideIn/slideOut (its crappy, but it has moves. Making it bounce would require playing with the y values):

```js
const Item = (props) => { 
  const {
    item:{title, isViewable}
  } = props
 
  // to get bounce effect, we will animate a translation
  const translateXY = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY()).current;
  const slideValue = 40
  const slideIn = () => {
    Animated.spring(translateXY, {
      toValue: {x:slideValue,y:5},
      duration: 250,
      useNativeDriver:false
    }).start();
  };
  const slideOut = () => {
    Animated.timing(translateXY, {
      toValue: {x:-slideValue,y:5},
      duration: 250,
      useNativeDriver:false
    }).start();
  };
  
  // fade in/out base on if isViewable
  if(isViewable || isViewable == 0)
    slideIn()
  else
    slideOut()
  const initialState={transform:[{translateX:-slideValue}]}
  const animation = {transform:translateXY.getTranslateTransform()}
  return (
    //add animation to Animated.View
    <Animated.View style={[style.itemContainer,initialState,animation]}>
      <View style={style.item}>
        <Text style={style.title}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    </Animated.View>
  );
}
```

Comment: u have used native animation.. It is helpful too.. but can u check how to add animatable library like i given in example

Comment: Im sorry I didn see you were using an animated library. Which one are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable - this one , but please don't delete the existing answer too , Its helpful.

Comment: added another answer that uses that library